# Facebook Site URL and Wall Sharing

Tags: facebook, settings, share

Is wall sharing (performed through the FB JS API) in any form related to the Site URL setting for a given application? Users don't actually log in to our website using the tool - they just share the URLs on their walls via an application we've setup.

We are looking for expert confirmation on the subject as we'd like to change the Site URL in support of a new login provider wrapper (Janrain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can share urls even if the Site Url is not supplied. But the domain should be listed in the "App Domains" box. This shouldn't be a problem since it supports multiple domains. An example would be both myapps.mydomain.com and myapps.myotherdomain.com are listed there. I think this is ok in your case.

Comment: This matches with our field test. We changed the URL and the sharing was not affected.